# Is $E(|X\log(X)|)$ finite whenever $E(X) = 1$?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

Asking for $X \ge 0$ under any probability measure $P$, does $\int X \, dP = 1 \implies \int |X\log(X)|\,dP < \infty?$

Comment: The reason the space between $X$ and $\log$ was too small, so that you saw $X\text{log}(X)$ instead of $X\log(X),$ is that you typed X\text{log}(X) instead of X\log(X). I corrected that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider

$$
P\left(X=\frac6{\pi^2}\cdot\frac{2^n}{n^2}\right)=2^{-n}
$$

for all positive integers $n$. Then $E(X)=1$, but

\begin{eqnarray}
E(|X\log X|)
&=&
\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{-n}\cdot\frac6{\pi^2}\cdot\frac{2^n}{n^2}\log\left(\frac6{\pi^2}\cdot\frac{2^n}{n^2}\right)
\\
&=&
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac6{\pi^2}\cdot\frac1{n^2}\left(\log\frac6{\pi^2}+n\log2-2\log n\right)
\\
&=&
\infty\;,
\end{eqnarray}

as the first and third term yield convergent series whereas the second one yields a multiple of the divergent harmonic series.